# How can i calculate the total amount of Multiple products in Javascript? Values are coming in AJAX

Tags: php

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'ajax_subtotal.php',
    data: listing_id=listId,
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(data)
    {
        if(data['result']=='success')
        {
            alert(data['pricing']);
        }
}
```

`data['pricing']` gives me the price of one product..The function is calling if product quantity is changed.  So, how can I calculate the total price of the multiple products at the same time??

Comment: Without seeing the entire object, it will be difficult to guess at what needs to be done.

Comment: provide more details. Unanswerable currently.

Comment: You didn't close brackets properly...!

Comment: you should have textbox where the product quantity is changed.. ?

Comment: Can you find what data returned on your ajax with Firebug

Comment: He should have much more, actually. So far I can only tell you: (product * quantity) + (other_product * quantity)..

Comment: chandresh_cool:- I have multiple products and their price calculated in AJAX. So i want to calculate the total amount of the multiple products. It will also calculate if i add multiple quantity of the same product.

Comment: @aliasgarvanak,Are you sending data from  ajax_subtotal.php using json_encode()?

Comment: Damien Pirsy:- But how can i get all the proiduct amount. My all product is coming in one "WHILE" loop.

Comment: first thing I can tell you is that, the approach of ajax request on every quantity change is not efficient. Why don't you save the unit price of each product in some hidden field?

Comment: @Jibran Khan:-<input type="hidden" name="NumberOfProperty[]" id="NumberOfPropertyTxt_<?php echo $id; ?>" value=""/> i am trying to save the product in to this field but failed to get the amount in Javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
First i store all the value in to the hidden field..

<input type="hidden" name="NumberOfProperty[]" id="NumberOfPropertyTxt<?php echo $id;?>" value=""/>

When my ajax is calling i got all the value in it..

var values=$('input[name="NumberOfProperty[]"]').map(function()
{
return this.value
}).get();
console.log(values);

In this i got my all price stored in to the array...then

var Total=0;
                        $('input[name="NumberOfProperty[]"]').each(function()
{
if($(this).val()>0)
{
Total+= parseFloat($(this).val());
}
});
$('#sub_total').val(Total);
$('#subtotal').html(Total);

I got all the value into the Total and assign it in to the sub_total id.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
First you have declare 
var total = 0
$.ajax({
 ...
 success:function(){
     if(data['result']=='success')
        {
           total += data['pricing'];
        }
   }
 });

atlast of the function alert(total);
```